# Why does the OpenCL cl.hpp (header-only) wrapper not break the One Definition Rule?

Tags: c++, opencl, gpgpu

OpenCL provides a header-only C++ wrapper for cl.h, called cl.hpp. It is shipped with some implementations but can also be gotten from khronos.org, since it only uses the OpenCL library.

It contains a lot of templates and inline stuff but also stuff like this:

```
namespace cl
{
 class Buffer : public Memory
 {
  Buffer (...stuff...)
  {
   // Constructor implementation
  }

  // ...
  // Other Constructors and such
  // ...

  Buffer& operator= (const Buffer& rhs)
  {
   // implementation
  }

  // ...

  Buffer createSubBuffer (...)
  {
   // implementation
  }
 }
}
```

Now here is my question: Shouldn't those implementations, which are in the classes definition but neither inline nor templated, be in violation of the One Definition Rule? What did I miss here?

Comment: Classes can always be defined in headers. Don’t you do this all the time?

Comment: I think he's referring to the class member function definitions

Comment: Correct, I meant the implementations of the members inside the classes definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## C++ ISO

7.1.2/3:

> **A function defined within a class definition is an inline function**. The inline specifier shall not appear on a block scope function declaration. If the inline specifier is used in a friend declaration, that declaration shall be a definition or the function shall have previously been declared inline.

3.2/4:

> **Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function** or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic required. The definition can appear explicitly in the program, it can be found in the standard or a user-defined library, or (when appropriate) it is implicitly defined (see 12.1, 12.4 and 12.8). **An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used**.

3.2/6:

> **There can be more than one definition of** a class type, enumeration type, **inline function with external linkage (7.1.2)**, class template, non-static function template, static data member of a class template, member function of a class template, or template specialization for which some template parameters are not specified in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements [...]